# How to create Spring Service integration test in Spock with MongoDB testcontainer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, spock, testcontainers

Suppose I have a service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  @Autowired OtherService otherService;
  @Autowired MyRepository myRepository;

  // some methods...
}
```

where `myRepository` implements `MongoRepository`.

I want to write an integration test for this class such that:

1. `otherService` is mocked
2. `myRepository` is autowired and uses a test container

What I tried so far is (test written in Groovy using Spock):

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [MyService.class, MyRepository.class])
@Testcontainers
class MyServiceIntegrationTest extends Specification {
  @Shared 
  static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.4.3")

  @Autowired 
  MyRepository myRepository

  @SpringBean 
  OtherService otherService = Mock()

  @Autowired 
  MyService testedService

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static mongoProps(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    mongoDBContainer.start()
    registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", () -> mongoDBContainer.getReplicaSetUrl())
  }

  // some tests...
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'myService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.xxx.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: EnableJpaRepositories ??????

Comment: can you share your project structure or can we find it in github?

Comment: @EddúMeléndez unfortunately, I can't share it due to my firm's policy. I think this question is clear and generic.